# BadMethodCallException Method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::share does not exist. error in laravel app

Tags: php, laravel

I've installed `maatwebsite/excel` with the command `composer require maatwebsite/excel` from command line on my laravel project. I've set the correct aliases and providers following the guide but when I run `php artisan make:export ExportTimesheet --model=Timesheet`, it throws an error:

> BadMethodCallException Method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::share does not exist

This is the method that generates the error:

```php
protected function bindClasses()
{
    // Bind the format identifier
    $this->app['excel.identifier'] = $this->app->share(function($app) {
        return new FormatIdentifier($app['files']);
    });
}
```

My providers and aliases are:

```
    'providers' => [

        /*
         * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
         */
        Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,
        Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider::class,

        /*
         * Package Service Providers...
         */

        /*
         * Application Service Providers...
         */
        App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        // App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,

    ],

    /*
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     | Class Aliases
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |
     | This array of class aliases will be registered when this application
     | is started. However, feel free to register as many as you wish as
     | the aliases are "lazy" loaded so they don't hinder performance.
     |
     */

    'aliases' => Facade::defaultAliases()->merge([
        // 'ExampleClass' => App\Example\ExampleClass::class,
        'Excel' => Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel::class,
    ])->toArray(),
```

This is my `composer.json`:

```json
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.0.2",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^9.19",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^3.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.7",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "*",
        "spatie/laravel-permission": "^5.8"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/pint": "^1.0",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^6.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^1.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "pestphp/pest-plugin": true
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Comment: Maybe you have the wrong package version from maatwerk compared to your current laravel version. Maybe you can share your composer.json?

Comment: @Techno I've shared

Comment: Are you trying to make a custom service provider? Where are you placing this code? what are you hoping to acheive?

Answer (score 18):

I am using laravel 9 .After running following steps everything seems to be fine.

1. Go to composer.json
2. Update "maatwebsite/excel": "3.1.48",
3. Run composer update
4. Go to config->app.php
5. Add to providers Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider::class,
6. Add to aliases 'Excel' =>Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel::class,
7. Run composer dump-autoload

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: In my case uncommand  extension=zip and extension=gd in php.ini file

Answer (score 4):

The error is caused by gd and zip extension not being enabled by default in your xampp / wamp server..
to resolved this ...
1 open your php ini file
2. go to gd extension and remove the ; before gd entension, likewise zip-extension
3. save the file again
4. restart your server
5. then re-install the package again : composer require maatwebsite/excel

- it should work, because that was how I'm able to resolved mine too when I came across this error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

My Solution is for Laravel Latest Version

1st go to the terminal and write

```
composer require maatwebsite/excel:*
```

it will install the package without any error

then Go to composer.json

Update "maatwebsite/excel": "3.1.48",

```
Run composer update
```

Go to config->app.php

```
Add to providers Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider::class,

Add to aliases 'Excel' =>Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel::class,

Run composer dump-autoload
```

it will work
if still not works ;

then go to php.ini (c:\xampp\php\php.ini)
and search ;gd make it
to

```
gd
```

---

```
 php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider" --tag=config
```